# Fogbugz for project management

Tags: scrum, task-management

I dont have too much experience with project management with [Fogbugz](https://www.fogbugz.com/) and everything I find about it is serveral years old. I've mostly worked with [Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/). Most of my experience with DevOps is as a developer and not project manager.

Is Fogbugz a good product for scrum project management for a small dev team? (devops will be used for repos, pipelines, artifacts and test plans)

I can't really find any reason why to choose Fogbugz and not DevOps, so please let me know if there are some good reasons for using Fogbugz in a scrum project?

Is there some key functionality of project management you got in Fogbugz and not DevOps and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are probably both looking over their shoulders at each other (and others, like [AWS DevOps](https://aws.amazon.com/devops/)), and copying the features most reported as missing, to the point that it's going to be difficult to tell them apart, eventually.

Meanwhile, to answer your question, I'll quote [StackShare](https://stackshare.io/stackups/azure-boards-vs-fogbugz):

FogBugz belongs to the "**Issue Tracking**" category of the tech stack, while Azure Boards can be primarily classified under "**Agile Project Management**".

Some of the features offered by **FogBugz** are:

- Issue and Bug Tracking
- Effortless Bug Reporting, Customizable Case Lists, and Full Case Histories
  Project Management
- Wikis, Evidence-based Scheduling, Task Outlining, and Reporting
  Customer Support
- Email Management, AutoSort, and Snippets

On the other hand, **Azure Boards<sup>(*)</sup>** provides the following key features:

- Track all your ideas at every development stage and keep your team aligned with all code changes linked directly to work items.
- Scrum ready - Use built-in scrum boards and planning tools to help your teams run sprints, stand-ups, and planning meetings.
- Built for insights - Gain new insights into the health and status of your project with powerful analytics tools and dashboard widgets.

<sup>(*) Boards within Azure Devops mimic the functionality of Atlassian's Issue & Project Tracking software, Jira. Within Boards you can create kanban boards, story items, feature items , backlog items, sprints and query items to query your entire project items.</sup>

Comment: Thank you. "FogBugz belongs to the "Issue Tracking" category of the tech stack" is exactly my experience. Then I will try to get accept for using DevOps also for project management